# How to accept both right and left references in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to have member function that accepts both left and right references to some class and moves it's object. Currently I have two separate functions:

```
void ThrSafeQueue::push(Obj&& x) {
  lock_guard(mutex_);
  queue_.push(x);
}
void ThrSafeQueue::push(Obj& x) {
  lock_guard(mutex_);
  queue_.push(std::move(x));
}
```

Comment: They're called lvalue and rvalue references.

Comment: Note for the 1st case you should call `std::move` too, note `x` is a named variable, thus an lvalue.

Comment: @user1810087 Just a note, they are now called forwarding references now per the standard.

Answer (score 4):

This is what a universal reference is for:

```
template<typename T>
void ThrSafeQueue::push(T && x) {
  lock_guard(mutex_);
  queue_.push(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

The syntax seems misleading. Here `&&` does not actually designate an rvalue reference, but a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) that will bind to either an lvalue or an rvalue, depending on the template call.

[std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) will, depending on whether its template is an rvalue on an lvalue, either degenerate to `std::move`, or a no-op in a case of an lvalue, exactly what you want.

This example will actually attempt to forward anything, and not just an `Obj`, to `push()`. This is probably ok, but if you would like to restrict the invocation of the template to be used only with `Obj`s, the usual tricks involving `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` can be employed, if needed.

Comment: The term "universal reference" is deprecated. Use "forwarding reference" instead

Answer (score 1):

The first option is to use template member function ([forwarding references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)), but it can't be virtual and may accept some other types instead of Obj in some cases:

```
template <typename T>
void ThrSafeQueue::push(T&& x) {
  lock_guard(mutex_);
  queue_.push(std::move(x));
}
```

The second option is to leave only function accepting right reference and `static_cast<Obj&&>` all left references. Instead of `static_cast` you may use `std::move`:

```
ThrSafeQueue t;
t.push(Obj{});
Obj o;
t.push(std::move(o));
```

Comment: Do note you can use SFINAE to constrain the template function.  Also the references are called lvalue and rvalue references.